# Which getline am I using?

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I'm a little bit confused about which getline() function is C++ using.
little code:

```
std::string name;
std::cout << "What is your name? ";
std::getline(std::cin, name);
```

I tough I was using std::getline from string header but when I mouse click on the getline() function the IDE redirects me to stdio.h and this is a C header.

There is a way in execution time for knowing which function am I using?

Ps: Yea I'm including string header (also if I don't what is his propose since I can remove it from everywhere I used it and everything still work, but this a question for another day).

EDIT:
qt-creator is redirecting me to this function inside stdio.h

```
/* Like `getdelim', but reads up to a newline.

   This function is not part of POSIX and therefore no official
   cancellation point.  But due to similarity with an POSIX interface
   or due to the implementation it is a cancellation point and
   therefore not marked with __THROW.  */
extern _IO_ssize_t getline (char **__restrict __lineptr,
                size_t *__restrict __n,
                FILE *__restrict __stream) __wur;
```

And this is even more strange because I'm using 2 parameters and here 3 are required...

Comment: Have you got `#include <string>`?  (there are different string headers)

Comment: 1) Headers can include other headers. 2) It can't be C header, due to the fact, that C doesn't have a concept of streams.

Comment: The stdio getline takes different parameters.

Comment: You also include `<iostream>` since you are using `std::cout`. This will import a bunch of other `getline`s. See [getline](https://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?search=getline). The IDE might just be getting the wrong one.

Comment: Which function gets called is known at compile time. There's no need to run to code to find out which function gets called.

Comment: My IDE brings me straight to `basic_istream<E,T>& getline(basic_istream<E, T>&, basic_string<E, T, A>&)` if I `#include <string>` and `#include <iostream>`.

Comment: @eyllanesc The IDE is likely important for this question.

Comment: @Algirdas  C does and always has had the concept of streams  - that's what all the functions such as fopen, fread an so-on work with. Admittedly, thrse are not the same as iostreams, but still....

Comment: @NeilButterworth What I was talking about, is: `std::istream`, `std::ostream`, and family.

Comment: It's very likely just a bug/defect in Qt Creator. It probably found the wrong `getline`. That's certainly not the overload actually being called.

Comment: The "version" of getline is (if the code compiles without diagnosable error) uniquely determined by the name and argument list at the call point. In your case, the one being called accepts a reference to `std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits>` (which is what `std::cin` is) and a `std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits, std::allocator<char> >` (what `std::string` actually is). The standard specifies it is in `<string>` but an implementation may show something different (e.g. other headers declare things form `<string>` or because `<string>` for that implementation includes other headers)

Comment: @Peter There's an additional and often overlooked factor for resolving overloads, and that's the list of which overloads are actually available at that point. In some cases a different set of `#include` can produce valid code with different behavior. For example if a header gives `void foo(double)` and you call `foo(0);` you can change the behavior by introducing another header that provides `void foo(int)`. I feel that saying that name and arguments uniquely determines the overload implies that nothing else can change the overload, but that's not the case. It's true for a fixed set though.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux - that's true, but in the case given by the OP (using a function that is specified in `<string>` and passing an argument of type `std::string` which is also specified in that header) there is no ambiguity.   Only one function is an exact match.